# Race condition in Backbone when fetching data in unit tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, backbone.js, race-condition

We are using Backbone (poorly) and Handlebars, Mocha and SinonJS for test. I continually run into an issue when trying to unit test other developers code. Seems there is a problem when a model or collection fetches data. The async call is not always completed when entering my unit test, so I often see these false positives on the build server.

The devs are not using **LayoutManager** or any other tool to manager the view life cycle. Can I add an `afterRender` function to the view to ensure all data is loaded? If so what would that function look like? Would I tap into the jQuery promise?

I have tried mocking the requests in the beforeEach method of test and calling the done function, but the problem seems to persist. Can someone point me to something that might help me ensure the view is rendered and fetch has completed before entering the test? Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and here is what I did.

### Callbacks helper

```
// The Callbacks module.
//
// A simple way of managing a collection of callbacks
// and executing them at a later point in time, using jQuery's
// `Deferred` object.
// 
// Source: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js#L1291
define(['jquery'], function($) {

    function Callbacks() {
        this.deferred = $.Deferred();
        this.promise = this.deferred.promise();
    }

    Callbacks.prototype = {
        constructor: Callbacks,

        // Add a callback to be executed. Callbacks added here are
        // guaranteed to execute, even if they are added after the
        // `run` method is called.
        add: function(callback, contextOverride) {
            this.promise.done(function(context, options) {
                if (contextOverride) {
                    context = contextOverride;
                }

                callback.call(context, options);
            });
        },

        // Run all registered callbacks with the context specified.
        // Additional callbacks can be added after this has been run
        // and they will still be executed.
        run: function(options, context) {
            this.deferred.resolve(context, options);
        }
    };


    return Callbacks;
});
```

### Core Collection

In this collection we have 2 important methods: `onReset()` and `collectionReset()`. The `onReset()` method should be how **Views** "listen" for the collection's **reset** event because it uses Promises.

The `collectionReset()` method is executed only when the collection's **reset** event has been fired, which at that point we consider the collection loaded and we **resolve** all the added callbacks.

This takes care of race conditions because the callbacks were added using the `onReset()` method and execute even when the event has been triggered prior to adding the callbacks.

When you create a new collection and make it inherit from this collection, you have to make sure to add the `reset` option when fetching: `(new ExampleCollection()).fetch({ reset: true })`

```
// The Core Collection - other collections inherit from this one.
// Source: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/03/get-a-model-from-a-backbone-collection-without-knowing-if-the-collection-is-loaded
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'app/callbacks'
], function($, Backbone, Callbacks) {

    var CoreCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        constructor: function() {
            Backbone.Collection.prototype.constructor.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));

            this.onResetCallbacks = new Callbacks();
            this.on('reset', this.collectionReset, this);
        },

        // The `onReset` method should be called by views to render collection data
        // when the particular collection has been loaded from the server.
        onReset: function(callback, contextOverride) {
            this.onResetCallbacks.add(callback, contextOverride);

            if (this.loaded) {
                this.onResetCallbacks.run(this);
            }
        },

        // Since this method is called only on the collection's `reset`
        // event, we assume that the collection has been fully loaded.
        collectionReset: function() {
            if (!this.loaded) {
                this.loaded = true;
            }

            // Execute all the `onResetCallbacks` callbacks.
            this.onResetCallbacks.run(this);
        }
    });

    return CoreCollection;
});
```

### Example view

In an example view you would do the following:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'handlebars',
],
function($, Backbone, Handlebars) {
    var ExampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
        id: 'example-view',
        template: Handlebars.templates.example,

        events: {
        },

        initialize: function() {
            // If it renders a collection from the server.
            this.collection = __collection_name__;
            this.collection.onReset(function() {
                // It's guaranteed to execute.
                // No race condition anymore!
                // ...
            });
        }
    });


    return ExampleView;
});
```

Comment: Very nice explanation! Very thorough! I will definitely utilize this!